# How is this a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Probably a stupid question, but the following statement is supposed to be a tautology (according to the solutions given, anyway). But I'm not sure how.

> $(A \lor B) \land ((A \land B) \rightarrow  \sim C)$

But if $A$ and $B$ are both false, $(A \lor B)$ is false, and hence the whole statement is. Am I losing my mind?

Comment: I see your confusion, so are you sure you've transcribed the problem correctly?

Comment: I suspect that it has a typo, and that the first conjunction should be a disjunction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: If so, the disjunction could be a conjunction without invalidating the tautology.  Maybe they just got switched.

Comment: @BrianTung Yup, I have transcribed it correctly. It probably is a typo. Thanks for the help.